# Wiring a WS2801

Tags: raspberry-pi, ground, led-strip

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frxb4n.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have a set of WS2801 LED's that I'm trying to connect to a Raspberry Pi, using a 'hat' that I bought. On the hat, I have four points to solder to: -, D, C and +. The LED's have: V+, CO/CI, DO/DI, and GND.

I'm assuming that the D goes to the DI, the C to the CI, the + to the V+ and the - to the GND? I mean that's all pretty self explanatory except the - to the GND is the only bit that threw me off really. I thought it was worth checking before I soldered anything, as I'm pretty new to wiring electronics and don't want to break anything.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We prefer schematics to words. There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. You should also check your spelling and punctuation for legibility.

Comment: The WS2801 is an LED driver IC, not a LED.

Comment: Ok thanks I'll have a look at the schematic button and edit my post checking my punctuation amd correct my terminology I'm dyslexic and struggle with my English but I'm sure i can make my question a bit clearer if I try again

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats the general idea. In electronics, ground is commonly also referred to as Voltage Negative, Zero volts or Minus, and notated as 0V, V-, Gnd, or simply "-". So you connect Ground to "-".

Make sure you are connecting to the DI and CI of the first led, as these are Data In and Clock In. Not the DO or CO, which are the outputs instead.

Comment: Awesome thanks for that I tried to Google but couldn't phrase it right thanks for the help